# Matching users algorithm

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, match, matching

I'm trying to create a matching algorithm for my website.

**Explanation**:

The matching itself supposed to be by filling some answers to questions and get matched to someone who answered matching answers.
* Some of the answers might be more than 1 answer.
* User can match with more than 1 person if he asks.

For example:
    Music genres you like(up to 3)? answer: Rock, Metal
    Languages you speak(up to 3)? answer: English, Spanish Chinese
    Features you like in people(up to 2)? answer: Tall, Skinny

The answers are from a pool of answers(drop down), the user can't write what he wants.

In the case i gave above some examples of good matches for this user would be:

```
    1. genre - Rock | language - english | features - Tall
    2. genre - Rock,Metal | language - spanish | features - Skinny
    3. genre - Metal | language - chinese | features - Skinny,Tall
```

The principle is that from each question at least 1 thing should match.

**The problem**:

So I'm struggling with how to create the algorithm that matches a user with other users.

I thought about putting each entry(search data) in a table inside a database,
and then querying separate lists for all the people that matches the user data.

So in this case to get all the lists i need, there needs to be 12 queries to get 12 lists:

```
    SELECT * from table WHERE genre="Rock" And language="English" And feature="Tall"
    SELECT * from table WHERE genre="Rock" And language="Spanish" And feature="Tall"
    SELECT * from table WHERE genre="Rock" And language="Chinese" And feature="Tall"
    SELECT * from table WHERE genre="Metal" And language="English" And feature="Tall"
    SELECT * from table WHERE genre="Metal" And language="Spanish" And feature="Tall"
    SELECT * from table WHERE genre="Metal" And language="Chinese" And feature="Tall"
    SELECT * from table WHERE genre="Rock" And language="English" And feature="Skinny"
    ..
    ..
```

Also i *don't* want to mix up the lists because i might want to connect 3 people and not 2 and then i don't want mix languages or other likes.

so in code that would be something like this:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < genres.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < languages.length; j++) {
            for(int k = 0; k < genres.length; k++) {
                list = SELECT * from table WHERE genre=genres[i] And language=languages[j] And feature=features[k]
            }
        }
    }
```

This approach feels a bit ugly and also it will require a lot of nested loops,
and in the future if i want to add questions, this will just add more and more nesting to the loops.

Not to speak about inserting each entry will be problematic as well because each user has array
for each question so each row in the table will need to contain just one of the elements from the array which means each user will have couple of rows in the database table.

How should i approach this problem/algorithm?

Thanks.

**Edit**:

To clarify because it wasn't clear enough,

A user that picked the answers "Tall" and "Skinny" should match with 2 other people who marked "Tall" OR 2 other people who marked "Fat" OR 2 other people who marked both "Fat" and "Tall"(same for other questions)

So in this case(only this question) i need 3 lists and the 2 people i will get eventually will have to be from only one of those lists.

Problem is that i don't want to do so many queries to get a lot of lists, especially when the matches for the user will eventually come from only one of those lists.

Comment: I have deleted my post because it does not answer your post @heapoverflow (and I am not sure to be able to provided a satisfactory answer). You should show the examples you provided to clarify the matching you want to get